# Japanese verses Chinese Chinese verses Japanese

Tags: cookware

Do Japanese and Chinese have different types/styles of pots, pans, serving dishes, stoves or other  containers to use for cooking?

Comment: Isn't that true for all cultures with specific cooking methods? Think paella pan, pita oven, bamboo mat, fondue pot... I believe your question is a bit too broad, what specifically do you want to know?

Comment: Short answer: Yes.